# With or without "on" before "the last Wednesday in August"

Tags: prepositions

As far as I know, we don't use prepositions before "last", "next", e.g. "last Wednesday", but a title in a book says "On the last Wednesday in August" and the content of the article is about festivals.

Answer (score 1):

Prepositions *are* used with “last” and “next” when the definite article is also used, so one certainly would say that a festival happens “on the last Wednesday in August”, or indeed “on the next Wednesday after Easter”.